# Is there a function in r to read multiple data files which have matching columns into a single dataframe?

Tags: r

I have multiple .txt files, all of which are similar in format but with different values and I want to combine them into a single dataframe.

Is there a function in r to read multiple data files which have matching columns into a single dataframe?

Comment: There is not an existing base function to do this. Often you would read all the data.frames into a list and then combine them. It's unclear from your description whether you want a merge or an rbind to collapse the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append all the datasets, you can do the following :

Store the names of your datasets in a vector using `dir()` :

```
> files <- dir("data/")
```

Read all your files using `lapply()` and `read.csv` or any other similar function (ie `read_csv()` in the `readr` package) :

```
> lfiles <- lapply(files, function(x) {read.csv(paste0("data/", x))})
```

Put all dataframes together using `do.call()` and `rbind`

```
> df <- do.call(rbind, lfiles)
```

Comment: `list.files(".", ".txt")` a bit safer than `dir()`